# Facebook Login Status getting saved? - Android

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have implemented Facebook Login Button and I am successfully able to get "Name, User Id, Email" from Current Access Token and the button  changes to "Logout"

When I am restarting the application, the button still shows "Logout"
Is the data getting saved somewhere? If yes, How can I retrieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is the data getting saved somewhere?

As such, no. It's not getting saved automatically in your phone (you can save it manually though). You're seeing `logout` because the Facebook access token is still valid, until you do a manual logout.

If you want to retrieve the Name, User Id, Email etc, you still have to use the access token to get it from the Facebook servers. [Referring to this official doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension), you can see that:

> Native mobile apps using Facebook's SDKs will get long-lived access tokens, good for about 60 days. These tokens will be refreshed once per day when the person using your app makes a request to Facebook's servers. If no requests are made, the token will expire after about 60 days and the person will have to go through the login flow again to get a new token.

You can call `AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()` in your code to get the current access token. Using that, you can fetch the fields from Facebook.

Comment: Oh that is exactly what I wanted 

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

```
/* For Facebook */
private CallbackManager mCallbackManager;
private LoginButton login_button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    login_button = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    login_button.setReadPermissions("user_friends");
    login_button.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, mCallback);
    login_button.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email", "user_birthday", "user_friends"));

}

private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> mCallback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {

                        // Here you get the response from the facebook
                        Log.e("LoginActivity Response ", response.toString());

                        try {

                            String Name = object.getString("name");
                            String Email = object.getString("email");
                            String Id = object.getString("id");

                            Log.e("Full Info : ", Name + " / " + Email + " / " + Id);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                });
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields", "id, name, email, birthday");
        request.setParameters(parameters);
        request.executeAsync();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException error) {

    }
};

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: Yes you need data from facebook. You will get that data on LoginResult

Comment: No, i am getting data successfully from facebook. But it is getting saved somewhere in the memory as when i am restarting the app, the button still shows Logout